# arcTween donut transition doesn't work in angular 4 when updating the chart

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, d3.js

This is my update method, which is takes the new data as an input

```
public updateChart(mockData?: any) {
this.path.data(this.pie(this.dataset))
.transition()
.duration(750)
.attrTween('d', <any> this.arcTween);}`
```

and this is my arcTween method:

```
public arcTween(a: any): any {
let i = d3.interpolate(this.current, a);
this.current = i(0);
  return function (t) {
    return this.arc(i(t));
  };
}
```

Problem when calling the specified method above:
core.es5.js:1084 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'arc' of undefined

a closer inspection shows that also "this" is also undefined.

How can i fix this issue? It seems that d3.js is not suitable for angular 4 :S

i tried a lot of workarounds, but everything leads to this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` becomes out of scope if used inside an internal function like this - it loses context. One fix is how **s.alem** has changed the code to add a `let that = this;` and then use `that` inside the function - `that` will continue to hold the value of `this`. Another way to try to fix it is to turn it into an arrow function:

(pseudocode, I have not tried this, but you'll get the idea)

```
public arcTween(a: any): any {
let i = d3.interpolate(this.current, a);
this.current = i(0);
  return t() => {
    return this.arc(i(t));   //this will be as expected
  };
}
```

Another way is if this is a method written on an object, you can call it via that object. So if `arcTween` is a method on the `animation` object, you could call it with

```
animation.arcTween()
```

and it will keep its `this` intact.

Hopefully one of those fixes the scope issue.

Comment: @szumbe  Excellent :) Don't forget to choose an answer to close out your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having a scope problem which you probably can solve like this:

```
public arcTween(a: any): any {
    let i = d3.interpolate(this.current, a);
    let that = this;
    this.current = i(0);
    return function (t) {
        return that.arc(i(t));
    };
}
```

Comment: i get this message: core.es5.js:1084 ERROR TypeError: that.arc is not a function, also when moving the let that = this inside the return function() doesnt work --> undefined

Comment: It seems like it is still a scope problem. Maybe you can share your whole controller.